# ubunt20.04_Errors An error occurred. nal to see what is wrong.The error message was: 'Error: Broken Count > 0'

Tags: package-management, helpfile

am haveing thise error now an body help me to solve it!

```
An error occurred.
Please run Package Manager from the right-click 
menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.
The error message was: 'Error: Broken Count > 0'. 
This usually means that your installed updates have unmet dependencies.
```

Comment: Quick answer for it

Comment: I would open a terminal and `sudo apt -f install` if for no other reason that to get messages and thus clues as to what issues there are. Most errors in my experience are the result of users adding inappropriate sources  (*reading the output of `sudo apt update` often provides clues on that; but it's not just reading the lines printed, but what isn't there as well*).

Comment: Thnx @guiverc Fixed it .. by remove broken pakeges and clean than reinstall and upgrade.<!!>